# Eyes are organs or organ of our body?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I stuck in the following sentence:

> Eyes are the most precious ***organ/s*** of our body.

We say 'eyes' and not an 'eye' as body's organ. Now, when I say 'Eyes are', do I need to mention them as a singular organ or a pair?

So, 'Eyes are the most precious ***organs or organ*** of our body'?

I know the basic rule of subject-verb agreement, but this sentence perplexes me.

Comment: *We say 'eyes' and not an 'eye' as body's organ.* Of course we do. MorganFR made it clear.

Comment: @Usernew - This question doesn't ask about _eye_ vs. _eyes_, it asks about _organ_ vs _organs_, and whether or not the plurality agreement between the two should be maintained.

Comment: @J.R. I know, but that was an aside information. :)

Answer (score 3):

In your sentence, there are two eyes, so, in your case, it should be plural.

> (Our) **Eyes are** the most precious **organs** of our body.

However, you should also consider the general term "**the** eye" (as opposed to your comment about "an eye"). It is most widely used that way when referring to the organ(s) (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_eye) for example), and in [expressions](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/eye).

> **The (Human) eye is** the most precious **organ** of our body.
>
> Invisible to **the naked eye**.

You may use whichever you prefer, but the verb (to be) should agree with the subject (eye/eyes).

Comment: That's the basic rule, but are there occasional exceptions? _After a game, my legs are the sorest part of my body._ That sounds acceptable to me. What about this one? _My shoes are my favorite part of this outfit._ I'm guessing that the O.P. knows the general rule, but is wondering about possible exceptions.

Comment: @J.R. As in every rule, there are obviously exceptions. "Part" is very special in this context. You can say "My legs are the sorest part..." but you would have to use the plural for "My legs are the sorest limbs..." "Part", "area" and other general terms for non-specific things can be exceptions, but there is nothing wrong with using the plural for them as well: "My legs are the sorest areas..." "Organ" in this context follows the same rule as "limb" because they are more specific.

Comment: That's an excellent comment that probably ought to be folded into your answer.